# Detect if stepping in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

To speed up macros, it makes sense to turn off screen refreshing with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`. However, this makes debugging much harder. I know I can manually set `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` in the immediate window, but I'm wondering if there is any way to detect that the code is stepping, and mute each instance of `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`.

I have a internal variable called StepCode, which stops the code at certain points, but I'm wondering if there is a better way...?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem to be honest. I wouldn't use the screen to debug, I'd use a watch, `Debug.Print` or `Debug.Assert`, breakpoints, etc.

Comment: I sometimes use a constant `DBUG = False or True` to switch on/off debug.print lines. You could have `Application.ScreenUpdating = DBUG` in place of `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`